# degrees of temperature and humidity

Tags: meaning, expressions

I am currently working on a game where the different areas of the map will have different climates. I wish to have 5 different levels of temperature and humidity for the different climates. I currently have the following descriptors(from lowest to highest) for the levels.

for temperature:
FREEZING, COLD, MILD, HOT, SCORCHING,

and for humidity:
ARID, VERY_DRY, DRY, HUMID, MOIST

Do you feel that these names are accurate? Any suggestions for more appropriate descriptors?

Comment: "Moist" seems quite a mild word compared to "humid", but I've not thought of a better one. "Saturated" might be a firmer word but does sound rather formal and may be inappropriate from a physics point of view.

Comment: That is the one that bothers me the most. I tried to think of synonyms for "Very humid". I realize now that moist means only slightly wet.

Comment: The [thesaurus](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/humid) yields *steamy, sultry, dank, clammy, muggy*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's a game, I think getting the point across quickly and making things easier to understand is the most important thing to consider. Thus, you should really not be afraid to use the word "very". I think I'd replace "mild" with "moderate". Also,

**Freezing, Cold, Moderate, Hot, Scorching**

is a good choice in my opinion, and works just as well as

**Very Cold, Cold, Moderate, Hot, Very Hot**

As for humidity:

**Very Dry, Dry, Moderate, Wet, Very Wet**

Would appear as a natural way to express humidity levels to me, with *very dry* being specific to deserts (i.e. arid climate) and *very wet* being specific to areas with rainforests (i.e. tropical wet climate).